# create layout for template in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to create template for my project.In my projects I'm using header and css and js and footer for all page.(i.e page1.blade.php,page2.blade.php,etc).while loading  each page it takes more time to load.so I need to create a common layout and load the content(i.e page1.blade.php,page2.blade.php,etc) in content section.

How to create master layout and load the page1.blade.php and  page2.blade.php and so on.I want to create link this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar.
    @show

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what your *page1.blade.php* could look like:

```
@extends('layouts.includes.default')

@section('content')

// Your content

@stop
```

You can read about Blade templates in the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

Comment: how to create route?

Comment: You can type Route::method('url','Controller@action') in your Route.php file. 
But I suggets going to https://laracasts.com and go through a couple of beginner series.

Answer (score 1):

IN your resouce foloder create sub folder by the name layout and there u create a file master.blade.php 
        Ex: resource->layout->master.blade.php

Now in your page.blade.php
just extend it 
using
      @extends('layout.master')

Comment: how to create route?

Answer (score 1):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h2>Your Content </h2>

@endsection
```

Comment: how to create route>?

Comment: `Route::method('url','Controller@action')`

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');

})->name('welcome');

Comment: Route::get('blade', function () {
    return view('child');
});  I caught InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: